# in swift, how do i get the string value from a print_r statement in php?

Tags: php, swift

```
print_r($response);
```

I have used Alamofire to call a GET request from php code that uses print_r (as above)

I use this to get the 'outputString' in Swift:

```
let outputString = NSString(data: data!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

however, I get an error if i use '.rangeOfString' to see if a string is in the response string, how do i do this?

Comment: There is so little information here that it will be very difficult to provide a quality answer. You are using AlamoFire but you are not showing any of that code.

Comment: i have edited the question - does it make more sense? @ryantxr

Comment: Why don't you print it and see what you got?

Comment: never mind, I have just used php to echo the string that i need, thanks anyways!